# Как задать цвет ячейки в excel таблице с apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Нужно задать цвет ячейки excel таблицы в java c помощью apache poi. Должна быть возможность задать любой цвет.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно создать стиль, указать тип заливки

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = xssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Затем можно задать любой цвет по RGB палитре следующим образом

```
XSSFColor backgroundColour = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(189, 215, 238, 0));
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(backgroundColour);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```